# How to create the Facebook SDK static library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I'm trying to integrate Facebook to my app in Xcode 4.3 and I'm stock in this step, i tried changing the scrip to :
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
 I put that exact line, them I use this line in Terminal:

```
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

and returns an error file not found.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Xcode actually installed in `/Applications`? If it isn’t, you need to move it there or change the base of the path to wherever it is.